# How can I plot an implicit function in pgfplots without having to use gnuplot?

Tags: pgfplots

I have been trying to plot a couple of really simple implicit linear functions using only pgfplots internal facilities.

Here is my MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{external}
\tikzexternalize
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}

\begin{axis}
\addplot[color=red]{3*x + 2*y - 2};
\end{axis}

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

When I run this, I get this error:

```
! Package pgfplots Error: Sorry, you can't use 'y' in this context. PGFPlots ex
pected to sample a line, not a mesh. Please use the [mesh] option combined with
[samples y>0] and [domain y!=0:0] to indicate a twodimensional input domain.
See the pgfplots package documentation for explanation.
```

This particular function can be made explicit, but I'd still like to know if it is possible to plot implicit functions with pure `pgfplots`. All the examples I have seen thus far call `gnuplot`.

Comment: @sudosensei I've been trying it with `\addplot3[mesh,samples=10,domain y=-6:4]{3*x + 2*y - 2};` now. I get a 3D plot with intersecting planes (there is another similar function that isn't in the MWE). I'm tinkering with the view settings to see if that gives me what I want, but still no luck.

Comment: @sudosensei I don't think this is the right approach, because these are supposed to be implicit functions in **R**, and not two-dimensional functions _z = f(x,y)_.

Comment: Well, plotting implicit functions take either an equation solver or a lot of memory and working time. It's overkill to want to do these things directly in LaTeX. Well, IMHO it's overkill to draw any functions in LaTeX, but that's another story. Besides `gnuplot`, you can try to use `sagetex` too.

Comment: Oh, I see. I seem to have misunderstood the question. Unfortunately, I am not a `TikZ`/`pgfplots` guru, so you'll just have to wait for the cavalry. `:-)` Is there a reason you want to avoid `gnuplot` though.? As far as I know, all the call to `gnuplot` does is export a data file that is plotted by `pgfplots`. So the plot you'd get would be identical to one produced directly with `pgfplots` internals.

Comment: @sudosensei This problem didn't seem that complicated to me, so I figured it could be done easily in pgfplots directly. Now I'm thinking this might be doable as a `pgfplots` contour plot.

Comment: I believe `pgfplots` uses `gnuplot` internally to generate the data points for the contour. If memory serves me right, the command you are looking for is `\addplot3[contour gnuplot,...]`.

Answer (score 2):

Actually, it is possible to draw implicit functions with LaTeX, if not with PGFPlots… but also in that case you need to cheat a little. Dan Luecking has implemented in its [`mfpic`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/mfpic) package, which is a (La)TeX interface to MetaPost (or METAFONT), a macro called

`\levelcurve[spec]{seed,step} {inequality}`,

which works quite well beyond certain conditions, as said in [the documentation](http://archive.cs.uu.nl/mirror/CTAN/graphics/mfpic/doc/mfpic-doc.pdf), p. 44-45:

> This figure macro produces a level curve of some function `F(x;y)`. There are three requirements
>   on the parameters for this to work correctly. First, in order to obtain the curve satisfying `F(x;y) =C`,
>   the `{inequality}` must be either `{F(x,y) > C}` or `{F(x,y) < C}`. Second, the level curve must
>   surround the point given by the `seed` paramter, and third, the inequality must be true at this seed
>   point.
>
> The command works by searching rightward from `seed` until it encounters the first point on
>   the level curve. It then tries to find a nearby point on the level curve and joins it to the first one, and
>   continues similarly until it finds it has returned near the starting point. The meaning of “nearby point
>   on the level curve” is the intersection of the level curve with a circle of radius `step` centered at the
>   previously found point. If the region defined by the inequality extends beyond the bounds of the
>   picture (as set by the \mfpic command), the region is truncated and the resulting curve will follow
>   along the picture’s border.

I've already used this macro to [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/224883/25768) [a similar question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/224861/folium-of-descartes), and it worked very well in that case. I've just applied it on your simple example:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[metapost]{mfpic}
  \setlength{\mfpicunit}{1cm}
  \opengraphsfile{\jobname}
\begin{document}
\begin{mfpic}[2]{-0.5}{2}{-0.5}{2}
  \levelcurve[p]{(0, 0), 0.01}{3*x + 2*y - 2 < 0}
  \doaxes{xy}
  \tlpointsep{2bp}
  \tlabels{[tr](0, 0){$O$} [tr](0.667, 0){$\dfrac{2}{3}$} [cr](0, 1){$1$} 
    [tc](\xmax, 0){$x$} [cr](0, \ymax){$y$}}
\end{mfpic}
\closegraphsfile
\end{document}
```

Typeset with LaTeX, then with MetaPost, and then with LaTeX again. The result is:

[image]

(As indicated in the documentation, the borders of the graph have been used to close the line which was the expected result.)

Still, as Paul Gessler noticed, an external program has worked behind the scene, namely MetaPost (be it as close to LaTeX as an external program can be).

Answer (score 1):

No, it is not currently possible to plot implicit functions natively using `pgfplots`.

The use of `gnuplot` (or some other external computation engine) is required for these types of plots at this time. Even contour plots in `pgfplots` require `gnuplot` or a sufficiently prepared data file.