# Folium of Descartes

Tags: pstricks, asymptote, pstricks-add

How to fill region on Folium of Descartes like this:

[image]

Here is my codes:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{pstricks-add}
\usepackage{pst-func}
\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[!ht]
\centering
\psset{algebraic=true,dimen=middle,dotstyle=o,linewidth=0.8pt,arrowsize=3pt 2,arrowinset=0.25,unit=4}
\begin{pspicture*}(-.5,-.5)(2,2)
\psaxes[linecolor=gray,xAxis=true,yAxis=true,labels=none,ticks=none]{->}(0,0)(-.5,-.5)(2,2)
\psplotImp[linecolor=blue,linewidth=1.5pt,plotpoints=500](0,0)(2,2){y^3-3*x*y+x^3}

\end{pspicture*}
\caption{Folium Descartes}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: You can make the code a little shorter: `algebraic=true` --> `algebraic` and `dimen=middle` --> `dimen=m`. Also, blank lines in `pspicture` environments are not a good idea.

Comment: It seems that the easy way around this problem is to use a parametric plot: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8017/how-to-increase-the-dot-resolution-of-implicit-curves-produced-by-psplotimp

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can fill if you use `\parametricplot`:

```
\documentclass[10pt,x11names]{article}
\usepackage{pstricks-add}
\usepackage{auto-pst-pdf}
\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[!ht]
\centering
\psset{algebraic=true,dimen=middle,dotstyle=o,linewidth=0.8pt,arrowsize=3pt 2,arrowinset=0.25,unit=3,plotpoints=2000}
\begin{pspicture*}(-2,-2)(2,2)
 \psset{linecolor=SteelBlue4, linewidth=1.2pt}
 \pscustom[fillstyle=solid, fillcolor=lightgray!25!LightSteelBlue2!10!]{
 \parametricplot{-0.99}{0}{3*t/(1 + t^3) | 3*t^2/(1 + t^3)}
 \parametricplot{-600}{-1.01}{3*t/(1 + t^3) | 3*t^2/(1 + t^3)}
 }
\pscustom[fillstyle=solid, fillcolor=LightSteelBlue2!25! ]{
 \parametricplot{0}{200}{3*t/(1 + t^3) | 3*t^2/(1 + t^3)}
 }
 \psline[linewidth=0.4pt, linecolor=black](-2.5; 45)(2.5 ; 45)
 \psline[linewidth=0.4pt, linecolor=black](-2,1)(2,-3)
\psaxes[linecolor=gray,xAxis=true,yAxis=true,labels=none,ticks=none]{->}(0,0)(-2,-2)(2,2)
\end{pspicture*}
\caption{Folium of Descartes}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: `\parametricplot{0}{200}{3*t/(1 + t^3) | 3*t^2/(1 + t^3)}` for the second `\pscustom` is enough and the `\closepath` is not needed

Comment: @Herebert: That's right. I even can't remember why I plit it in two. Perhaps a remnant of some preliminary testing. Thanks!

Answer (score 15):

Done with [`mfpic`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/mfpic), a LaTeX interface to MetaPost. To draw the folium you can use the cartesian form directly, thanks to the handy `\levelcurve` command of this package, so long as you write it as an inequation and you provide a point that verifies this inequation (here (1, 1)). The resulting curve is filled with the `\gfill` command with the desired color as an option.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage[metapost]{mfpic}
  \setlength{\mfpicunit}{1cm}
  \opengraphsfile{\jobname}
\begin{document}
\begin{mfpic}[2]{-0.5}{2}{-0.5}{2}
  \draw\gfill[blue+green]\levelcurve{(1, 1), 0.01}{y**3 - 3x*y + x**3 < 0}
  \doaxes{xy}
\end{mfpic}
\closegraphsfile
\end{document}
```

To be compiled first with (PDF)LaTeX, then with MetaPost, and finally with (PDF)LaTeX. The result is as follows:

[image]

Answer (score 14):

In [Metapost](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/107489/what-is-metapost-metafont-and-how-can-i-get-started-using-it), you could just make the folium a closed path and fill it.

[image]

I've used the (rather simpler) polar form of the equation below.

```
prologues := 3;
outputtemplate := "%j%c.eps";

beginfig(1);

u := 2cm;

path xx, yy, folium;

xx = (1/2 left -- 2 right) scaled u;
yy = (1/2 down -- 2 up)    scaled u;

drawarrow xx withcolor .4 white;
drawarrow yy withcolor .4 white;

folium = (origin 
  for theta=1 step 1  until 89:  
    -- (3*sind(theta)*cosd(theta)/(sind(theta)**3+cosd(theta)**3),0) rotated theta
  endfor 
  -- cycle) scaled u;

fill folium withcolor .9[blue,white];
draw folium withcolor .67 blue;

endfig;
end.
```

And here's a fuller version, with the equation moved to a function, and showing how to extend the folium and pick out the loop as a sub path of it.

[image]

```
prologues := 3;
outputtemplate := "%j%c.eps";

beginfig(2);

u := 2cm;

path xx, yy, folium, loop, asymptote;

xx = (2 left -- 2 right) scaled u;
yy = (2 down -- 2 up)    scaled u;

drawarrow xx withcolor .4 white;
drawarrow yy withcolor .4 white;

% "a" is the scale factor
a = 1;
vardef r(expr t) = right scaled (3*a*sind(t)*cosd(t)/(sind(t)**3+cosd(t)**3)) 
                         rotated t enddef;

% define the folium with some wings 
b = 30; % should be less than 45
folium = (r(-b) for theta=1-b step 1 until 89+b: -- r(theta) endfor -- r(90+b)) scaled u;

% define the loop to be the part from theta=0 to theta=90
loop = subpath(b,b+89) of folium -- cycle;

% define an appropriate segment of the asymptote
asymptote = ( xpart point 0        of folium,    -xpart point 0        of folium-a*u) 
         -- (-ypart point infinity of folium-a*u, ypart point infinity of folium    );

% now draw them
fill loop withcolor .9[blue,white];
draw folium withcolor .67 blue;
draw asymptote dashed evenly;

endfig;
end.
```

Answer (score 14):

The folium of Descartes in parametric form with `Asymptote` (pun intended):

[image]

```
// file fod.asy
// 
// to get fod.pdf, run `asy -f pdf fod.asy` 
//
size(8cm);
import graph;
import fontsize;
defaultpen(fontsize(9pt));

texpreamble("\usepackage{lmodern}");

pen curvepen=darkblue+0.8bp;
pen linepen=darkred+0.8bp;
pen fillpen=orange+opacity(0.5);

real 
xmin=-20, xmax=-xmin, 
ymin=-20, ymax=-ymin; 

xaxis(xmin,xmax,RightTicks(Step=10,step=5,OmitTick(0)));
yaxis(ymin,ymax, LeftTicks(Step=10,step=5,OmitTick(0)));

real a=10;

real r(real t){return 3*a*sin(t)*cos(t)/(sin(t)^3+cos(t)^3);}; 

real tmin=-0.16pi, tmax=pi/2-tmin;

guide 
loop=polargraph(r,0,pi/2)--cycle,
curve=polargraph(r,tmin,tmax);

fill(loop, fillpen);
draw(curve,curvepen);

pair 
p=point(curve,0),
q=point(curve,length(curve));

draw((p.x,-p.x-a)--(-q.y-a,q.y),linepen);
```

A little more advanced example:

[image]

```
// file fodsp.asy
// 
// to get fodsp.pdf, run `asy -f pdf fodsp.asy` 
//
size(8cm);
import graph;
import fontsize; defaultpen(fontsize(9pt));
texpreamble("\usepackage{lmodern}");

pen[] fillpen={
  red, orange, yellow, green, lightblue, blue, darkblue
};

real 
xmin=0, xmax=20, 
ymin=0, ymax=20; 

xaxis(xmin,xmax,RightTicks(Step=10,step=5));
yaxis(ymin,ymax, LeftTicks(Step=10,step=5));

real ra(real t, real a){return 3*a*sin(t)*cos(t)/(sin(t)^3+cos(t)^3);}; 
real r(real);
guide loop;

real a, a0=10, da=1;
int n=fillpen.length;

real t; pair p;
a=a0;
for(int i=0;i<n;++i){  
  r=new real(real t){return ra(t,a);};
  loop =polargraph(r,0,pi/2)--cycle;  
  filldraw(loop, 0.7fillpen[i]+0.3white,fillpen[i]);
  t=atan(2^(1/3));
  p=r(t)*(cos(t),sin(t));
  unfill(circle(p,0.7));
  label("$"+string(a)+"$",p);  
  a-=da; 
}

label("$r(\theta)=\displaystyle"
+"\frac{3 a \sin\theta\cos\theta}{\sin^3\theta+\cos^3\theta}$, "
+"$\theta=[0,\frac\pi2]$, "
+"$a="+string(a0-(n-1)*da)+"$--$"+string(a0)+"$"
,((xmin+xmax)/2,ymax),S);

shipout(bbox(paleyellow,Fill));
```